# 5355 UDP svchost.exe Dnscache

Tags: networking, dns, cache

We have an application for network traffic monitoring and are trying to figure out what traffic should be allowed or blocked. One of the entries is desktops talking to other desktops on the network via port 5355 and it is mapped to Dnscache service.

Should this traffic be allowed between workstations on the same network and what would happen if we blocked it?

Comment: Did you gather any information by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port is used by Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution protocol within the Dnscache Service. This is a necessary service so that the PC's can resolve each other's names on a subnet when there is no DNS server or when the DNS server is not providing Name Resolution. Based on the article below this is used only when all other attempts to resolve names fail, it would be a bad idea to block it on your network.

Here is a reference link to the subject:
https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2217263&seqNum=8